# Bootstrap Switch Event Handler not working on laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, bootstrap-switch

Bootstrap Switch does not toggle, and only loads when the page is reloaded. 
on the first load I have a result like this :
[image: Result]

If i reload the page i have the good result :

[image]

I am working on laravel 4.

Any idea? thanks in advance

code :

```
    {{ HTML::style('assets/layout/css/admin3/layout.css') }}
{{ HTML::style('assets/layout/css/admin3/themes/default.css') }}
{{ HTML::style('assets/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css') }}
{{ HTML::style('assets/layout/css/admin3/custom.css') }}



<label class="control-label col-md-3">Status</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <input type="checkbox" checked class="make-switch" data-size="small" name="status">
</div>


<!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
<!-- BEGIN CORE PLUGINS -->
{{ HTML::script('assets/plugins/jquery.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/plugins/jquery-migrate.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/plugins/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/plugins//jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/plugins/jquery.blockui.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/plugins/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/plugins/jquery.cokie.min.js') }}
<!-- END CORE PLUGINS -->
<!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
{{ HTML::script('assets/plugins/jquery-validation/js/jquery.validate.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/scripts/metronic.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/scripts/quick-sidebar.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/scripts/admin3/layout.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/scripts/admin3/demo.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/pages/scripts/index3.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/plugins/bootstrap-switch/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js') }}

<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {       
           // initiate layout and plugins
            Metronic.init(); // init metronic core components
            Layout.init(); // init current layout
            Demo.init(); // init demo features
            index3.js;
        });   
</script>
```

Comment: Please, post your HTML code.

Comment: code? console error?

Comment: I put the code in a new edition of the post question, hope it can help.